# How to clear spool space in teradata

Tags: c#, ssis, sql-server-2008-r2, teradata, data-warehouse

I am bringing in data from teradata to sql server using SSIS. Now the DFT to bring data runs inside a for loop counter. Each time we pass a list of ids to the teradata query and bring in the data. I have a script component as the source inside the DFT because size of the query is more than 4000 characters. First few times the loop runs well but after sometime it starts throwing spool space error. Is there any way to clear the spool space after each loop. I do not have access to the tables in teradata server.

Comment: Unless you are using volatile tables and not dropping them, there is no way to "clear" spool space.

Comment: You might also want to look at the skew on your query.  Are you basically running out of spool on a single AMP while all the others look fine?  If so, maybe you need to consider whether your primary index was a good choice

Comment: Without the actual source code and some more details about the tables there's no way to help you. There's a high probablity that the `LOOP` is not really needed :)

Comment: Try commiting after each batch

Comment: I am not using volatile table and I am only reading data so not sure about what to commit. As i mentioned I do not have access to see the indexes in the server side. The loop is required because SSIS is being used to pull the data from teradata , which has a restriction of 4000 characters on the query size, so I am not able to pass all the IDs together to the query. Kindly let me know if there is any other way.

Comment: Put your IDs in a volatile table. You can do that in batches if you have to. Then use that in your query.  Anything beyond that is pure speculation.

Comment: You can also bypass SSIS altogether, and bring data directly using Teradata as a linked server.